# Chalk in React Native doesn't style

Tags: react-native, terminal, styles, chalk

I'm trying to style my console log with this library: chalk.

In the terminal I see the output without errors but no red colors. Any one has used it before?

```
import chalk from 'chalk';
```

and then

```
console.log(chalk.red('This remain white as default'));
```

I'm running it on OSX, React native 0.61.5

Comment: SOLVED:
I needed to add 
const ctx = new chalk.Instance({level: 3});
and then 
console.log(ctx.red('red text'));

Answer (score 5):

As the [document description](https://github.com/chalk/chalk#usage).

You have to require before using it.

Example:

```
const chalk = require('chalk');  //Add this
```

And check the setting of `chalk.level`

```
const ctx = new chalk.Instance({level: 3});

Level   Description
0       All colors disabled
1       Basic color support (16 colors)
2       256 color support
3       Truecolor support (16 million colors)
```

Then you can `console.log(ctx.red('red text'));`

Comment: Import does the same thing as require().
I alse tested it, no difference.

Comment: Have you check [this](https://github.com/chalk/chalk#chalklevel)?